# Avoiding simultaneous promise, best practices?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an analytical dashboard. A dashboard is build out of one or more visualizations and upon initial rendering the dashboard I retrieve the minimal info required to render a visualization.

After that, I want to 'preload' additional information that enables me to interact in a more detailed way with each individual visualization. This information is stored in a schema. One or more visualizations can share the same schema.

Therefore I want to load the schema once, and after that return the cached schema to avoid multiple server requests.

The challenge I am solving is to avoid multiple visualizations, at the same time, from requesting this information. When one visualization is requesting the schema and we have multiple requesting the same schema, I don't want to invoke multiple server requests but have them wait for the first one to finish and then use the cached version.

What would be the best way to approach this? I could do something really nasty like keeping track of ongoing XHR requests and then do a setTimeout(retry,500); on all subsequent requests untill the first XHR request has finished... but maybe there is a way to restructure the promise in such a way to create a dependency between follow up requests on the same schema?

Any tips would be appreciated. I know how to fake it in an ugly way but I want to do it in the right way.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SchemaManager() {
        this.schemas = {}; // precached schemas
    }
    SchemaManager.prototype = {
        Load: async function (schemaId) {
            this.schemas[schemaId] = "loading";
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Xhr({
                    url: `/api/lightweightfield/${schemaId}`,
                    type: 'json',
                    action: 'GET',
                    callbackOk: function () { resolve(this); },
                    callbackError: function () { reject(); }
                });
            });
        },
        Get: async function (schemaId) {
            if (!this.schemas[schemaId]) {
                let result = await this.Load(schemaId).catch((e) => {
                    new ErrorDialog({ title: 'Failed to get schema', content: schemaId });
                    return null;
                });
                this.schemas[schemaId] = result.response;
            } else {
                console.log('cache hit');
            }
            return this.schemas[schemaId];
        }
    }

    let sm = new SchemaManager();
        
    (async function () {
        var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
        console.log('visualization 1',schema);
    })();
    (async function () {
        var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
        console.log('visualization 2', schema);
    })();
    (async function () {
        var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
        console.log('visualization 3', schema);
    })();
    (async function () {
        var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
        console.log('visualization 4', schema);
    })();
    (async function () {
        var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
        console.log('visualization 5',schema);
    })();

    
</script>
```

Comment: Does anything ever need to call `Load` *other* than `SchemaManager` itself? Because if you're caching the result, `Get` and `Load` should probably be combined into one (external) API.

Comment: Probably yes. I think what will eventually going to happen is that I will refactor Load to become private method and I will only expose the Get method.

The only responsibility of Load is to get the information and put in in the cache.

The responsibility of Get is to get the information, and depending on availability in the cache return the cached instance or do a one time retrieval from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want to *serialize* calls to `Get`. (I'd also probably make `Load` private so that `Get` is the only external API for getting schemas from `SchemaManager`.) You can do that by keeping track of the promise `Get` returns (for a given schema) and having the next call to `Get` for that same schema wait for the previous promise to settle before doing anything.

You've agreed in a comment with the idea that `Load` should be private, so I've moved it out of `SchemaManagers`'s API.

Something along these lines (see `***` comments):

```
function SchemaManager() {
    this.schemas = {}; // precached schemas
}
function loadSchema(schemaId) {
    console.log(`Loading ${schemaId}`);
    // *** Probably worth promise-enabling `Xhr` so we don't need a wrapper every time
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Xhr({
            url: `/api/lightweightfield/${schemaId}`,
            type: "json",
            action: "GET",
            callbackOk: function() {
                console.log(`Loaded ${schemaId}`);
                resolve(this.response);
            },
            callbackError: (error) => { // *** I assume an error is provided?
                // *** Failed to load, so clear the promise from cache
                reject(error); // *** Pass along the error if provided
            }
        });
    });
}
SchemaManager.prototype = {
    Get: async function (schemaId) {
        let cacheEntry = this.schemas[schemaId];
        if (cacheEntry instanceof Promise) {
            // *** Previous load in progress, wait for it to complete
            try {
                console.log("Waiting for previous load");
                const schema = await cacheEntry;
                console.log("Using previous load result");
                return schema;
            } catch {
                // *** Previous load failed, try again
            }
        } else if (cacheEntry) {
            // *** The cache entry is a schema
            console.log("Cache hit");
            return cacheEntry;
        }
        // *** Need to load the schema
        console.log("Start load");
        cacheEntry = this.schemas[schemaId] = loadSchema(schemaId);
        try {
            const schema = await cacheEntry;
            console.log("Caching result for next time");
            this.schemas[schemaId] = schema;
            return schema;
        } catch {
            // *** Didn't get it
            this.schemas[schemaId] = null;
            throw error;
        }
    }
}

let sm = new SchemaManager();

(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 1",schema);
})();
(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 2", schema);
})();
(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 3", schema);
})();
(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 4", schema);
})();
(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 5",schema);
})();
```

Live Example:

```js
// Stand-in for Xhr
function Xhr({url, callbackOk}) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const n = url.lastIndexOf("/");
        const id = url.substring(n + 1);
        callbackOk.call({response: {id}});
    }, Math.random() * 100);
}
// Stand-in for ErrorDialog
function ErrorDialog({content}) {
    console.error(content);
}
function SchemaManager() {
    this.schemas = {}; // precached schemas
}
function loadSchema(schemaId) {
    console.log(`Loading ${schemaId}`);
    // *** Probably worth promise-enabling `Xhr` so we don't need a wrapper every time
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Xhr({
            url: `/api/lightweightfield/${schemaId}`,
            type: "json",
            action: "GET",
            callbackOk: function() {
                console.log(`Loaded ${schemaId}`);
                resolve(this.response);
            },
            callbackError: (error) => { // *** I assume an error is provided?
                // *** Failed to load, so clear the promise from cache
                reject(error); // *** Pass along the error if provided
            }
        });
    });
}
SchemaManager.prototype = {
    Get: async function (schemaId) {
        let cacheEntry = this.schemas[schemaId];
        if (cacheEntry instanceof Promise) {
            // *** Previous load in progress, wait for it to complete
            try {
                console.log("Waiting for previous load");
                const schema = await cacheEntry;
                console.log("Using previous load result");
                return schema;
            } catch {
                // *** Previous load failed, try again
            }
        } else if (cacheEntry) {
            // *** The cache entry is a schema
            console.log("Cache hit");
            return cacheEntry;
        }
        // *** Need to load the schema
        console.log("Start load");
        cacheEntry = this.schemas[schemaId] = loadSchema(schemaId);
        try {
            const schema = await cacheEntry;
            console.log("Caching result for next time");
            this.schemas[schemaId] = schema;
            return schema;
        } catch {
            // *** Didn't get it
            this.schemas[schemaId] = null;
            throw error;
        }
    }
}

let sm = new SchemaManager();

(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 1",schema);
})();
(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 2", schema);
})();
(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 3", schema);
})();
(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 4", schema);
})();
(async function () {
    var schema = await sm.Get("schemas-1953-A");
    console.log("visualization 5",schema);
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

In that, I've set it up that `Get` tries the `loadSchema` again if the previous one failed. Alternatively, you might store some kind of "failed" object in the cache to indicate that the schema can't be loaded.

A couple of other minor notes:

- The overwhelmingly-common convention in JavaScript code is that only constructor functions start with an upper case letter. So `Load` and `Get` would conventionally be written `load` and `get`.
- *Replacing* the `prototype` property on a constructor function is not best practice, not least because you mess up the `constructor` property the object put there by the JavaScript engine set up. Instead, write to properties on it — or better yet, use `class` syntax.

Comment: Thanks upfront, going to take some time digging into your suggestions and code. Looks like you are chaining promises, ... brilliant actually.

[edit]
Already looked into it ... simply beautiful .. love it. Very much appreciated.
[/edit]

Comment: This solves the problem but makes the architecture worse overall. IMO the original question implemented caching way more cleanly, making `Load()` responsible for fetching (except for the unnecessary first line) and `Get()` responsible for caching and error reporting. The code in this answer, however, breaks cohesion and introduces unnecessary coupling, spreading caching layer across `Load()` and `Get()`. This should not pass review in my opinion.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff - I really struggled with having both `Load` and `Get` being public, and seem to have not quite circled all the way back on it (blame lack of coffee). Thanks for the nudge (though perhaps that last sentence was unnecessary, eh?). The OP has now agreed `Load` can be private, so I've updated. (Though really, they shouldn't both have been touching `this.schemas` even if both are public, so thanks again.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a familiar issue…

You could try refactoring your methods so that:

- `this.schemas` maps schema IDs to retrieval promises, not schema data.
- `Get()` returns `this.schemas[schemaId]`, populating it by calling `Load()` if needed.
- `Load()` does not touch `this.schemas` *at all*, its responsibility is strictly to construct a query and return a promise of schema data. As a side-effect, it becomes easier to test. (If it were me I’d also switch to a functional pattern and move this function out of the manager, but that depends on your conventions.)

As a result, callers of `Get()` would receive the same single promise that should be resolved for all of them when request is complete. Later callers may receive an instantly-resolving promise.

Here’s a minimal sandbox demonstrating the scenario: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-wu-x8vgl6?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It would be better to put the code **in** the answer, rather than just having an off-site link. People shouldn't have to go off-site to see the full answer; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. This definitely doesn't qualify for a "link-only answer" flag, but it would be much more complete with the code *in* it. :-)

Comment: Looking into this code as well, again thanks. I'm not too picky or a zealot in terms of solid principles. If it looks good, and pretty ok in terms of being maintainable I'm happy.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree, but codesandbox offered an interactive demo and I’m not sure how to incorporate that into an SO answer. Generally though, as per my answer, the proposed change is very small and is more or less 2–3 changed lines.